# Windows 10 Creators Update > Every tab in Settings > Network & Internet and Connection menu won't open

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, crash, windows-10-v1703

After installing new Creators Update, I've got issues with my Network settings.
When I open Settings app, then click on Network & Internet and choose any tab, app just crashes.
Only a few tabs are working (such as Proxy, Data Usage, Airplane mode and Status). Every other tab crashes the settings app.
Also, when I open Connections menu, I didn't see any available Wi-Fi networks:

[image: picture]

**In Event Viewer I got these errors:

1. When trying to open Connection menu:**

```
Faulting application name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x58ccbd2e
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x3280d1b7
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x000000000000ad32
Faulting process id: 0x1434
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60bb3e11ef3
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: 2ddc8310-5447-4568-8203-281ea72a9db2
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.15063.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
Faulting application name: RuntimeBroker.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x782fe8f8
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xb79b6ddb
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000282b1
Faulting process id: 0xd1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60bd07f627d
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 79ebe539-7d5f-4f06-b3af-a45279273caa
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**2. When opening Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-Fi:**

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x7c8bd05a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xb79b6ddb
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ac526
Faulting process id: 0x1fac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60ccd930c6a
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: c13e5b15-f4cb-44b9-b303-12b3856c862b
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

**3. When opening Settings > Network & Internet > Ethernet:**

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x7c8bd05a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xb79b6ddb
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ac668
Faulting process id: 0x1c0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60cf1b08acd
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 732762d5-3f9f-43e7-b858-ea1ccbb2a0bd
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

**4. When opening Settings > Network & Internet > Dial-Up:**

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x7c8bd05a
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x72781892
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000003b164c
Faulting process id: 0x2374
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60d0aa44636
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 51f17a76-56d1-4f3d-80c5-dfaf9c974bf5
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

**5. When opening Settings > Network & Internet > VPN:**

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x7c8bd05a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xb79b6ddb
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ac668
Faulting process id: 0xf5c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60d2c12d137
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 71c59d41-4e09-456a-9fd6-06e9130c20ab
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

**6. When opening Settings > Network & Internet > Mobile HotSpot:**

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x7c8bd05a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xb79b6ddb
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000282b1
Faulting process id: 0x1750
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b60d3fddc490
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 8934d578-ef60-4485-9893-007567c5e4fd
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Safe boot.
2. `sfc /scannow`.
3. DISM (Check, Scan, Restore Health).

UPD:
I created another user and all the Settings worked. The problem only with the main user account.
UPD2:
Windows 10 Repair Upgrade didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Your missing several updates based on the build version of those ddls

Comment: [Follow this](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) to generate crash dumps. zip all dmps into a ZIP and also share it via OneDrive. I'll look at it and submit it to my Microsoft contacts so that they can debug it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avo5ajuosG2RkBR21-rrrQyHAQTZ
Here is the dump. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Windows 10 Repair Upgrade](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085).

If it didn't help, create a new account and check, if you're still having this problem.
I solved my problem by creating a new user account.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Crash dumps showed some problem with RASMan module. I solved the problem by deleting some dial-up connections I had. Try deleting any dial-up or VPN connections you have.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dump shows the following issues:

`RuntimeBroker.exe` crash because of `INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_rtutils.dll!AcquireWriteLock` (accessing null pointer):

```
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects
03 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
04 kernel32!WerpReportFault
05 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter
06 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0
07 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
08 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
09 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
0a ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0b ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection
0c ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended
0d ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection
0e rtutils!AcquireWriteLock
0f rtutils!TraceCreateServerThread
10 rtutils!TracePrintfExA
11 rasapi32!IsRasmanServiceRunning
12 rasapi32!LoadRasmanDllAndInit
13 rasapi32!RasRegisterEntryChangeNotification
14 RasMediaManager!Windows::Networking::UX::Internal::NetmanClient::_RegisterRAS
15 RasMediaManager!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CTaskWrapper<<lambda_9e5327b33811052196ca3464d5821a1c> >::Run
16 RasMediaManager!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_ThreadProc
17 RasMediaManager!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ExecuteThreadProc
18 RasMediaManager!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ThreadProc
19 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
1a ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

The call `rasapi32!IsRasmanServiceRunning` indicates that is is checked if the `Remote Access Connection Manager (RasMan)` service is running or not. Check if the service runs.

`ShellExperienceHost.exe` crash is caused by failed remote procedure call:

```
Stowed Exception #1 @ 0x0000016793bf9cf0
    0x800706BE (FACILITY_WIN32 - Win32 Undecorated Error Codes): The remote procedure call failed

    Stack    : 0x167936c99f0
        7ffd2e48b431 combase!RoOriginateError+0x51
        7ffd20792d43 wincorlib!Platform::Details::ReCreateException+0x63
        7ffd20792bf2 wincorlib!__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException+0x12
        7ffcf6f2142d NetworkUX!__abi_WinRTraiseException+0xb5
        7ffcf6f6f105 NetworkUX!Windows::Networking::UX::INetworkUXManager::GetUXCategories+0x41
        7ffcf6f724db NetworkUX!NetworkUX::ViewContext::_Initialize+0x1d7
        7ffcf6f01840 NetworkUX!<lambda_1d9043053e3afd6a4260a1edea240dd5>::operator()+0x184
        7ffcf6f4dce7 NetworkUX!Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler::Invoke+0x27
        7ffcf6f5b6a6 NetworkUX!?__abi_Windows_System_Threading_WorkItemHandler___abi_IDelegate____abi_Invoke@?Q__abi_IDelegate@WorkItemHandler@Threading@System@Windows@@2345@UE$AAAJPE$AAUIAsyncAction@Foundation@5@@Z+0x16
        7ffd1d373c54 threadpoolwinrt!Windows::System::Threading::CThreadPoolWorkItem::CommonWorkCallback+0xa4
        7ffd1d3736a4 threadpoolwinrt!Windows::System::Threading::CThreadPoolWorkItem::BatchedCallback+0x84
        7ffd2efd3031 ntdll!TppWorkpExecuteCallback+0x131
        7ffd2efd1999 ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x6c9
        7ffd2eb92774 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
        7ffd2f000d61 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

This could be also caused because of the not running RASMan service which provides VPN and network.

The settings app `SystemSettings.exe` crashes because of  `INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_c0000005_rasapi32.dll!StringCopyWorkerW` Also access of null pointer in Remote Access API. So this could be also related to the service issue.

Comment: This service is running. I've tried to restart it but it didn't help.
Here is the list of all services: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avo5ajuosG2RkBhkHasiR3ZVlqCg

Comment: hm. I see you can fix it with a new account. Is your main account using LiveID/MSAccount or offline account?

Comment: MS Account.
I probably, will move all the data to a new account. Thank you for help!

Comment: ans now you used a local offline account for testing?

Comment: I tried both new local and new ms account and they both worked.
Also, I tried to convert my main account into local - didn't solve the problem.
It seems, that windows creators update broke something in the registry and system files.

Comment: ok, looks so and now the tools crash because of the corruption. Post your account workaround as answer if that works